# how to disable javascript function on a specific condition

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

The situation is:
I have a canvas and draw things on mousedown, and I have a generate button that generates new canvas' again you can draw things in same way.
BUT the problem is when you click the previous canvas it started to draw the new one. It must not draw the new canvas the function has to stop there.
Here is the drawing function:

```
canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
if (!painting) {
    painting = true;
} else {
    painting = false;
}

lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
};

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
if (painting) {
    mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    // find all points between        
    var x1 = mouseX,
        x2 = lastX,
        y1 = mouseY,
        y2 = lastY;


    var steep = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1));
    if (steep){
        var x = x1;
        x1 = y1;
        y1 = x;

        var y = y2;
        y2 = x2;
        x2 = y;
    }
    if (x1 > x2) {
        var x = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = x;

        var y = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = y;
    }

    var dx = x2 - x1,
        dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
        error = 0,
        de = dy / dx,
        yStep = -1,
        y = y1;

    if (y1 < y2) {
        yStep = 1;
    }

    for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
        if (steep) {
            ctx.fillRect(y, x, 1, 1);
        } else {
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }

        error += de;
        if (error >= 0.5) {
            y += yStep;
            error -= 1.0;
        }
    }



    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;

}
};
```

Here is jsfiddle for the issue http://jsfiddle.net/regeme/eV6kW/3/
any help would be great.

Comment: your question is more confusing tha your code!!!

Comment: ok,so the previous canvas cant be used when you comeback on it??

Comment: you can understand if you look jsfiddle.. generate a canvas and try to draw something to first one you can see that it will draw the second one.. this is the problem..

Comment: when you click the previous one you cannot see any drawing on it thats ok but it is drawing the next one which is weird.. you move your mouse on first canvas but it draws on next one

Comment: the reason is.its performing drawing on the same id...after creating canvas what you need is to assign id to that 2nd canvas...detect mouseover of respective canvas...and switch drawing to respective canvas

Comment: hmm I couldnt get it, how can you assign an id to the element that you create dynamically? can I request from you to edit it on jsfiddle..

Comment: under the generate function I did newCanvas.id="ncanvas"; and also change the newCanvas.mousedown to ncanvas.mousedown same did to mousemove but it did not work

Comment: element.setAttribute("id", "canvas_2");

Comment: same issue persists.. I did not get the mouseover issue what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `onmouseup` to the code, to make it draw only when mouse is held down, and the problem was due to the manually created first canvas and its callbacks. 
*Using this way clear will clear the canvas currently being dealt with.*

Look at the code for more insight:
http://jsfiddle.net/cryostat/grb8e/1/